# How to use wp-nicescroll plugin in WordPress site

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I've this personal wordpress site:
www.RagaBhakti.com
where I'm trying to replace the ugly vertical and horizontal scroll bars with nicescroll.
So I went to http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-nicescroll/installation/
and installed and activated the nicescroll plugin.

Since I'm new to Wordpress, I don't know what the next steps are in order to see the scroll bars change to nicescroll.
If there is some Jquery stuff that needs to be added to the actual pages, it would be helpful to know in detail how to go about doing this.

Thanks.

Comment: The answer by Jean-Francois wasn't useful.

Answer (score 0):

As I see your website now, jQuery and NiceScroll loads properly and works.

Notice that the scroll bar accutally appears only when you scroll with the scrollwheel. You have to customize it to suite your needs in the options of the plugin, in your Wordpress Admin section.

Comment: that is not the scrollbar from Nicescroll. Those are scrollbars from earlier style sheet #scroll {width: 475px; float: left; margin: 10px; overflow: auto; color: #3a424a; font-size: 11pt; height: 450px; }